# How to send a customized message through gcm and get its response?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I want to send customized message through gcm like a question with options and get the reply of that question from the receiver. 
In simple terms I want to make a voting app which uses GCM service for asking questions and getting response.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android-How to set Custom notification sound for GCM messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25861729/android-how-to-set-custom-notification-sound-for-gcm-messages)

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked [Sending Upstream Messages](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/upstream#sample-send)? A code Block from the source Link:

```
try {
    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    data.putString("my_message", "Hello World");
    data.putString("my_action","SAY_HELLO");
    String id = Integer.toString(msgId.incrementAndGet());
    gcm.send(SENDER_ID + "@gcm.googleapis.com", id, data);
    msg = "Sent message";
}
catch (IOException ex) {
    msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
}
```

You can add your Votes in `data`. Also you might wanna send your GCM `token`, that you receive in `RegistrationIntentService.onHandleIntent()`. This token can then be used by the server to uniquely identify you and send messages to you directly via `GCM`.

Check [Downstream Messaging Via HTTP Post](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/downstream#http_post_request), your JSON will  look something like this.

```
https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

{
    "data": {
        "score": "5x1",
        "time": "15:10"
     },
     "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1..."
}
```

Where "to" has the device's token.